# Python won't let me use i or x's when i do for loop commands. I have tried items and letters and it just isn't working

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
names=["Billy","Joey","judy"]

for i in names:

       print(names)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for i in names: print(i)` ?

Comment: Show the full error, or if it runs, then show what's wrong.   While an experienced programmer can tell at a glance what's the problem, you need to get in the habit of asking a full question.  Sometimes you'll realize the solution while doing that extra work.  In this case, ask yourself, what is `i`, what is `names`.  Print both and watch them evolve in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You are essentially printing your list of names three times (once for every element in the list). What I assume you are trying to do is:

```
names = ["Billy", "Joey", "judy"]

for i in names:
    print(i)

>>> Billy
>>> Joey
>>> judy
```

Here `i` takes on the value of each of the elements of the list in turn. So the first time through the loop `print(i)` will return `Billy`, the second time `Joey` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a name from `names` to the variable `i`, then you don't use it...

There are two ways to iterate with a for loop in python:

The first one, allegedly "more pythonic" is to iterate over each item like this: In this case the for loop is more like `for each item in items`, and the convention is to use a singular variable for the elements out of the iterable.

```
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

The second, issued from the c or c++ like languages is to iterate over the indices of a sequence, and retrieve each item via this index: The convention is to use a letter like `i, j, k`, or (arguably better) 'idx, jdx...'

```
for idx in range(len(names)):
    print(names[idx])
```

A third way combines both, and returns a tuple `(index, item)`, using the convenience function `enumerate`: It is used in cases where you need both.

```
for idx, name in enumerate(names):
    print(idx, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

names = ["Billy", "Joey", "Judy"]

for i in names:
    print(i)

when you iterate, you automatically have given i the assignment of taking each value in the list one at a time. you assigned all the values in names to i. you dont print names anymore, you print i